# Subtracting weekends and public holidays from Date in only native js

Tags: javascript

I've been tasked with subtracting x weekend days and public holidays from any given date. Coming from a Python background, I would use [workalendar](https://pypi.org/project/workalendar/) to solve this in five minutes. I'm currently scratching my head on this.

**Goal**

The script will be used with a date picker. The user will pick a business day, and it will inform the user of the previous x business days. A visualisation of this

```
|------------|
| datepicker |
| 18/12/06   |
|------------|
x working days before: y
x working days before: y
```

The locale is the UK, and I'm using the [Gov.uk bank holidays json](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json) to grab public holidays, as the script needs to account for substitute public holidays.

**Problem**

Currently, I am using this logic

```
    while (!foundFour) {
        if (dayOfWeek === 0 || dayOfWeek === 6 || bankHolidays.includes(dateString)) {
            alert('The day you\'ve selected falls on either a weekend or a bank holiday. Please select a working day.');
        } else {
                    while(!foundFour) {
                        if (!foundFour) {
                            fourDays = new Date(startDate - counter * oneDay);
                            if (fourDaysDow !== 0 || fourDaysDow !== 6 || !bankHolidays.includes(fourDaysStr)) {
                                workingDays++;
                                var fourDaysDow = fourDays.getDay()

                                fourDaysY = startDate.getFullYear()
                                fourDaysM = zeroPad(startDate.getMonth() + 1, 2)
                                fourDaysD = zeroPad(startDate.getDate(), 2)
                                fourDaysStr =  fourDaysY + '-' + fourDaysM + '-' + fourDaysD

                                if (workingDays === 4) {
                                    foundFour = true;
                                }
                            } else {
                                fourDays.setDate(fourDays.getDate() -1);
                            }
                }
                counter++
                console.log(fourDays)
            } 
        }
    }
```

This produces the following output

```
Date 2018-12-05T00:00:00.000Z   
Date 2018-12-04T00:00:00.000Z      
Date 2018-12-03T00:00:00.000Z  
Date 2018-12-02T00:00:00.000Z
```

The expected output is

```
Date 2018-12-05T00:00:00.000Z   
Date 2018-12-04T00:00:00.000Z      
Date 2018-12-03T00:00:00.000Z  
Date 2018-11-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

I don't see where the issue is here. Full script for reference

```
/*  collection-date.js
    A script designed to find x number of working days prior to any given date  
*/

// A data endpoint for bank holidays
let bankHolidaysData
// Bank holidays for England and Wales
let england
// An array of bank holidays
let bankHolidays = []

// A boolean specifying whether or not a date is a holiday
let isHoliday = false

// Bool for finding 4 days in the past
let foundFour = false
let fourDays

// Used to subtract the dates
let counter = 1.
// Used as a index for number of days passed
let workingDays = 0
let oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

// Used to format our dates to match that of gov.uk
let startDateY, startDateM, startDateD, fourdaysY, fourDaysM, fourDaysD, startDateStr, fourDaysStr

// Get the current UK bank holidays - We use the Gov.UK API to account for substitute days
fetch('https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json')
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    // Send the data to getBankHolidays
    .then(data => getBankHolidays(data))
    // log any errors for the IT monkeys
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)});


function getBankHolidays(data) {
    // Parse the data
    bankHolidaysData = data
    // Capture the events from the API
    england = bankHolidaysData["england-and-wales"].events

    // We need to add leading zeros where a day or month is represented by a single number
    zeroPad = function(num, pad) {
      return ((Math.pow(10, pad) + num) + '').slice(1);
    };

    // Add individual dates to bankHolidays array
    for (let index = 0, length = england.length; index < length; index ++) {
        bankHolidays.push(england[index].date)
    }

    // Instantiate a date object from the dateString variable 
    var startDate = new Date('2018-12-6');
    // Get the day of a week as a number, 0 Sunday
    var dayOfWeek = startDate.getDay();

    startDateY = startDate.getFullYear()
    startDateM = zeroPad(startDate.getMonth() + 1, 2)
    startDateD = zeroPad(startDate.getDate(), 2)

    dateString =  startDateY + '-' + startDateM + '-' + startDateD
    while (!foundFour) {
        if (dayOfWeek === 0 || dayOfWeek === 6 || bankHolidays.includes(dateString)) {
            alert('The day you\'ve selected falls on either a weekend or a bank holiday. Please select a working day.');
        } else {
                    while(!foundFour) {
                        if (!foundFour) {
                            fourDays = new Date(startDate - counter * oneDay);
                            if (fourDaysDow !== 0 || fourDaysDow !== 6 || bankHolidays.includes(fourDaysStr)) {
                                workingDays++;
                                var fourDaysDow = fourDays.getDay()

                                fourDaysY = startDate.getFullYear()
                                fourDaysM = zeroPad(startDate.getMonth() + 1, 2)
                                fourDaysD = zeroPad(startDate.getDate(), 2)
                                fourDaysStr =  fourDaysY + '-' + fourDaysM + '-' + fourDaysD

                                if (workingDays === 4) {
                                    foundFour = true;
                                }
                            } else {
                                fourDays.setDate(fourDays.getDate() -1);
                            }
                }
                counter++
                console.log(fourDays)
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop you have

```
if (fourDaysDow !== 0 || fourDaysDow !== 6 || !bankHolidays.includes(fourDaysStr))
```

Those should be && operators. 
If its NOT Sunday AND NOT Saturday AND NOT a bankholiday 
(Saturday is NOT sunday, so the OR expression would be true in your code)

It comes from this Boolean algebra theorem - which is crucial to know when you find yourself inverting the Boolean components of an expression

```
NOT (A AND B) == NOT A OR NOT B
NOT (A OR B) == NOT A AND NOT B
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Mike! I've given that a go, and I've now got an infinite loop (But without weekends or holidays!!) on my hands. It seems there are more flaws in the code. I'm going to accept your answer, as in the scope of the question you've given me what I need.

Comment: The first time you hit that line, fourDaysDow has never been set, so is undefined.